# I think I found someone spamming, but so far they haven't been detected

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam

I was doing some review tasks, and ran into these two responses:

[image]

and:
[image]

I then checked the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2662502/egg-head).  **There are 6 answers there, which are basically all the same (the account was created today)**.  So, instead of flagging them all, I figured that I would make a meta post.  For future reference, is this the correct course of action?

**EDIT:**
I was going to flag them the first time around, but the questions all asked for C/C++ decompilers, so I wasn't sure what to do.  I wanted to close the questions, but I didn't have that option in the review, so I oked them.

Comment: The correct course of action is to just flag *one* of their posts and explain in the flag that you think they're spamming in all of their posts. :)

Comment: Destroyed.  Next?

Comment: Well that was fast.  Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is more deadly than being linked to on meta

Comment: As an aside, Steve, search might even reveal more, but not (anymore?) in this case: [`url:"*demono.ru*"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*demono.ru*%22).

Comment: good catch, @SteveP.!